# code helpe me please `CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path "_id" for model "State"`

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Getting this CastError:  Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" (type string) at path `"_id"` for model `"State"`

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const modelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: String });
const modelName = "State";

if (mongoose.connection && mongoose.connection.models[modelName]) {
  module.exports = mongoose.connection.models[modelName];
} else {
  module.exports = mongoose.model(modelName, modelSchema);
}

if (data.state) {
  if (mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(data.state)) {
    const stateCheck = await State.findById(data.state);
    if (!stateCheck) {
      res.json({ error: "State dont exist" });
      return false;
    }
    updates.state = data.state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, use code formatting when asking your question. Your code is hard to read without proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The value in `data.state` might be an empty string.

Mongoose tries to cast an empty string to ObjectId and fails.